# Weird MouseEnter, MouseLeave behaviour of Border in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events, border

This is the XAML part.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Border Name="myBorder"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Width="100"
                Height="100"
                MouseEnter="MyBorder_OnMouseEnter"
                MouseLeave="MyBorder_OnMouseLeave">
        </Border>

        <StackPanel Width="150"
                    Height="150"
                    Background="Red"
                    MouseEnter="StackPanel_OnMouseEnter"
                    MouseLeave="StackPanel_OnMouseLeave"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Here is the C# part

```
       private void MyBorder_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MyBorder_OnMouseEnter");
        }

        private void MyBorder_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("MyBorder_OnMouseLeave");
        }

        private void StackPanel_OnMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("UIElement_OnMouseEnter");
        }

        private void StackPanel_OnMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("UIElement_OnMouseLeave");
        }
```

When I hover over border element MouseEnter, MouseLeave events fire both. When mouse leaves the border MouseEnter, MouseLeave events fire again. With stackpanel it behaves the way I expect. Why is this happening?

[Watch this to see the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Trb3.gif)

Comment: Try to set the `Background` of the `Border`.

Comment: Amazing. Problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't set the `Background` property of the `Border` to a `Brush`, the unpainted area is considered to belong to the parent element.

If you set the `Background` to `Transparent`, the events will get raised as expected:

```
<Border Name="myBorder"
    Background="Transparent"
    BorderBrush="Black"
    BorderThickness="2"
    Width="100"
    Height="100"
    MouseEnter="MyBorder_OnMouseEnter"
    MouseLeave="MyBorder_OnMouseLeave">
```